# Google Places is not returning correct results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=24.878178,67.066552&radius=2000&types=food&sensor=false&key=YOUR_KEY

I have been trying to find restaurants near to my places but whenever i just try to find it gives me zero_results.

second thing the place i mention here was the location of a restaurant when i tried to search that place on google map it returned me the same restaurant with the category food / restaurant /pub

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

> 24.884488,67.175256

I also tried to find a airport under 5000 meters of the above location but unable to find while i started my GPS and moved from the above location to airport and it was only 800 meters from the above location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=24.8844879,67.1752557&radius=500&types=food|restaurant|establishment&sensor=true&name=food|restaurant|cafe|shisha|bar|coffee|burger|chicken|pizza|hut|tikka|tandori&key=YOUR_KEY
```

I have tried to run the following query as all the food places in karachi represented as establishment. But it's not showing me the results in 500 meter radius of my current location and also showing me the results with the same name places in different areas which are around 20-30 km far from my place.